# How to create an App in PowerBI AppSource marketplace similar to Salesforce Reports App

Tags: salesforce, powerbi, marketplace, appsource

I want to build an PowerBI App similar to [Salesforce Reports](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi/909545e0-1c5e-44a9-b9db-bae412465c89?tab=Overview) App for Power BI in the AppSource market place

[image: Salesforce Report app]
[image: List of Salesforce Reports]

1. It expects the user to provide Salesforce credentials
2. It fetches all reports (tabular + summary) and lists on the right hand side
3. The user selects a report and the data corresponding to the report is fetched from Salesforce using a REST API call and a Dataset is created for the Salesforce Report.

I need to build something similar and I don't find the relevant documents.
1. Where do I can view the source code for the above app? Is it open source?
2.Is there any documentation on how to develop similar apps?

The above App is quite different from other Apps in the AppSource marketplace since this is not a content pack nor a solution template as well.

Comment: [1](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/First-steps-Create-my-own-AppSource/td-p/177516)

[2](https://appsource.microsoft.com/pt/partners#getStarted)

[3](https://smpprodresources.azureedge.net/partnerresources/Microsoft%20AppSource%20Partner%20Listing%20review%20guidelines.pdf)

Comment: @user5226582 I don't want to develop a content pack with structured data like github or jira, I need to create dataset alone

Answer (score 3):

That app was developed by Microsoft years ago as a Content Pack, it is not open source and there is no documentation for it, beyond this "getting started" page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-connect-to-salesforce

I would look at the Solution Template for Salesforce.  This is a wizard that spins up an instance of a data extract + SQL db + Power BI model for you.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BusinessPlatformApps/tree/dev/Source/Apps/Microsoft/Released/Microsoft-SalesforceSalesManagement

The generated components are all "open source" in that you can edit them.

Microsoft's template engine that generates app instances is also "open source", which probably doesn't matter for your scenario.  In case it does, you can find it here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BusinessPlatformApps

Comment: The other content packs contains Dashboard + Report + Dataset, in my case I want to create a dataset alone like the salesforce report app and I don't have the structured data so I can't use it as Solution Template

Comment: The Power BI model covers Report + Dataset. Dashboards are lightweight and easy to build. The data extract + SQL db components give you a better architecture with more flexibility.

Comment: I have unstructured data so I can't generate .pbix from Power BI Desktop

Comment: I'm stumped - so your app actually has nothing to do with Salesforce?

Comment: Yes, I want to build a similar app